# table row toggle by clicking td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check the fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/mv7Y5/89/

am trying to achieve to toggle the table row by clicking the td,
which is not happening please help needed.

```
    $(function() {
    $(".details").hide();
    $('.show-details').click(function(e) {
        $(this).next("tr").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? It seems like fiddle is working

Comment: try clicking on first one. as i said am trying to get JavaScript click action inside td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `next()` on the `td` that gets clicked (on the first cell, anyway). What `next()` does is it finds the nearest *sibling* of the element in question that matches the selector. There is no `tr` that is a sibling of the `td` that gets clicked. You need to make sure that you're calling `next()` on the `tr`, so it can find the *next* `tr`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".details").hide();
    $('td.show-details').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().next("tr").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Additionally, your markup in that jsfiddle is a little screwy (you've got an inconsistent number of columns in your rows, for example, which I believe may be the result of some typos.)

Answer (score 0):

In your first row, you have the class name "show-details" on the "td". On the subsequent rows, the class name is on the "tr" elements. Since you are using ".next()" to find a "tr", the class should be on the "tr" as in the second, third and forth rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class='rowToClick'><td>click me</td></tr>
```

Next, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
         {
             $(".rowToClick").click(function() { $(this).nextUntil(".rowToClick").toggle(); });
         });
```